# Arraylist to DefaultComboBoxModel

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, arraylist

I am trying to update the contents of a JCombobox through a refresh button and to do this I am attempting to use the Defaultcombobox Model. Below I have my code:

```
public GUI2() {
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
    contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    setContentPane(contentPane);
    StickWidget Left = new StickWidget();
    Left.setName("Left Stick");
    contentPane.add(Left.draw(), BorderLayout.WEST);
    StickWidget Right = new StickWidget();
    Right.setName("Right Stick");
    contentPane.add(Right.draw(), BorderLayout.EAST);

    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    contentPane.add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));

    DefaultComboBoxModel newModel = new DefaultComboBoxModel(ReadJoystick.read().toArray());

    JPanel panel_1 = new JPanel();
    panel.add(panel_1, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    combobox = new JComboBox(newModel);
    combobox.setPrototypeDisplayValue("XXXXXXX"); 
    panel_1.add(combobox);
    JButton btnRefresh = new JButton("Refresh");
    btnRefresh.addActionListener(this);
    panel_1.add(btnRefresh);
    newModel = new DefaultComboBoxModel();
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    newModel.removeAllElements();

        newModel.addElement(ReadJoystick.read().toArray());

    combobox.setModel(newModel);
}
```

ReadJoystick.read() returns an arraylist that is supposed to be converted to an array and passed into the new model. Evertime I press the refresh button, java throws a null pointer exception and I have no clue why.

Why does my program not work the way it is?

What would be the proper way to use the NewModel?

Thanks!

EDIT: The error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at xxx.xxxxx.xxxxxx.xxx.GUI2.actionPerformed(GUI2.java:78)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6516)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6281)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4872)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4698)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4698)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:747)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$300(EventQueue.java:103)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:706)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:704)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:720)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:718)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:717)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is in constructor, I think you have `newModel` variable as instance variable, but you are creating new one:

```
DefaultComboBoxModel newModel = new DefaultComboBoxModel(ReadJoystick.read().toArray());
```

Rewrite this to

```
newModel = new DefaultComboBoxModel(ReadJoystick.read().toArray());
```

This statement:

```
newModel = new DefaultComboBoxModel();
```

in constructor is still for local variable, so I would remove this line or use `this.newModel` instead

Comment: @maskaconvnik Thanks! adding `newModel = new DefaultComboBoxModel(ReadJoystick.read().toArray());` worked!